# I want to display word document content in any textbox which supports in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

there is one linkbtn , on click i have to display word document content inside any textBox which supports, i used simple textbox but am facing the formatting problem. and also it does not show image. there is any idea for problem in display word document content inside any textBox .
i dont know about **richtextbox**, can i get any help, please send me desired code to sandeep.dpkar@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET essentially boils down to html. You're going to run into problems rendering rich-content like word documents into html. This is not a trivial solution and you're likely going to have to spend a lot of time on this.

Word can however export to raw html, from which you could import, but it wouldn't presentable/editable in a text-box without heavy heavy amounts of javascript making your own **WYSIWYG editor**.